# How to solve 'Syntax error at line 131 : ``' is not matched.' error

Tags: shell, ksh

I am new to script writing. I have encountered the mentioned in the title i.e 'Syntax error at line 131 : ``' is not matched.' . The code at line 131 is commented out. I think the line below might be causing the problem. Could anyone direct me how the code below should be written? I need to output the value of scp and ssh command to determine whether the code was succesfully executed.

```
scpstat=`echo scp $INPUTDIR/work_dir/$f $EUSER@$ESCSYS:$EDIR/build/. |
ssh $EUSER@$ECSYS "chmod 660 $EDIR/build/$f;chgrp 107 $EDIR/build/$f;chown 103 $ESCDIR/build/$f;rename $ESCDIR/build/$f $ESCDIR/work/$f"'
  status=$?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the ` (backtick) before `echo` is not matched, as the error suggests.  It looks like the ' (apostrophe) at the end of the second line should be a backtick instead.

Some people think it's better style to use `$(...)` rather than `...`, and this is surely a good example of why.

Comment: Yes, I'm one of those people so +1. It's also a lot easier to nest `$()` than backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to begin with you have an opening **`**, and you don't have a closing one. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is often hard to reach the line numbers mentioned in the script errors. It is because if you include another script within your script (done by specifying  *. scriptname* in *ksh*) then the actual length of the original script changes at runtime. If there are errors in the included script then line numbers could be misleading because you cannot reach those lines. I feel that the error, in your case, is in the called script and not the one you are looking into. Check if you are calling/including any other script and try running it separately. This way you probably can isolate the problem.